# Why in SQLAlchemy base.metadata.create_all(engine) in python console not showing table?

Tags: python, linux, database, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to create database and insert values in it. I am using postgres database. I do not see any error when I do following

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/mydatabase')
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
>>> Base = declarative_base()
>>> from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
>>> class User(Base):
...     __tablename__ = 'users'
...     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
...     fullname = Column(String)
...     password = Column(String)
...     
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', password='%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)


>>> User.__table__
```

gives me

```
Table('users', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', Integer(), table=<users>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('fullname', String(), table=<users>), Column('password', String(), table=<users>), schema=None)
```

But when I run

```
>>> Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Nothing shows up, 
In document it is given that table and its attributes are shown
But nothing is seen after running Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Could some body suggest some solution ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to see the commands SQLAlchemy is sending, you want to turn `echo` on in the engine:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://...', echo=True)
```

Of course, you could always just look at the database afterwards with `psql` or another tool.